# Camel RejectedExecutionException on sending to seda queue

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-camel

My code looks as follows:

```
static ProducerTemplate producer = null;
...
public void process(Exchange exchange) {
    if (producer == null) {
        producer = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
    }

    for (Message msg : messages){
        Map<String, Object> headers = Maps.newHashMap();
        headers.put("DisplayMessages", true);
        producer.sendBodyAndHeaders("seda:aggregate-messages?blockWhenFull=true&size=500", msg, headers);
    }
}
```

I'm getting a `RejectedExecutionException null` thrown on the line `producer.sendBody...`.

From what I can tell this is normally caused by trying to send multiple asynchronous exchanges down a non asynchronous route. But isn't SEDA asynchronous ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to code your processors as thread-safe. And the code above is **not** thread safe.

You should initialize and cleanup logic in the `doStart` and `doStop` methods according to the lifecycle

- http://camel.apache.org/lifecycle

There you can setup the producer template once, and then your processor can become thread-safe.